# VirtualHost does not work on my vps (ovh)

Tags: dns, virtualhost

I am trying to peak my dimitri-dumont.fr domain name on my vps, however, it does not work.

I'm currently using apache2 and my vps is on ubuntu.

- My domain name is pointing to the IP address of my vps (configured in A).
- I created the site folder in /home/dimitri/html
- After that, I did:

```
sudo chown -R dimitri /home/dimitri/html 
sudo cmod -R 755 /home/dimitri/html
```

- I create a dimitri-dumont.fr.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available and here is the content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@dimitri-dumont.fr
    ServerName dimitri-dumont.fr
    ServerAlias www.dimitri-dumont.fr
    DocumentRoot /home/dimitri/html
    #Redirect permanent / https://www.dimitri-dumont.fr 

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/dimitri/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dimitri-dumont.fr
    ServerAlias www.dimitri-dumont.fr
    ServerAdmin contact@imitri-dumont.fr
    DocumentRoot /home/dimitri/html

    <Directory /home/dimitri/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride none
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After that, i did :

```
sudo a2ensite dimitri-dumont.fr.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did you check your `error.log`?

Comment: Also, your `<VirtualHost *:443>` is clearly misconfigured, check for example https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Https